# Prolog: script doesn't halt

Tags: prolog

I'm currently trying to learn prolog. I hope you can help..

I have three rules:
reverse - retrieves the reverse of a list
startswith - checks if the second list is a prefix of the first list
suffix - checks if the first list is a suffix of the second list

```
reverse([H|T], Y) :- append(Z, [H], Y), reverse(T, Z).
reverse([], Y) :- Y = [].

startswith(_, []).
startswith([Xh|Xt], [Yh|Yt]) :- Xh=Yh, startswith(Xt, Yt).

suffix(X, Y) :- reverse(X, XR), reverse(Y, YR), startswith(YR,XR).
```

reverse and startswith seem to work as they should. 
But suffix doesn't stop calculating. I cannot understand why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, it's a bad idea to pass variables that have yet to be unified to predicates that you will unify later. Essentially, `append(Z,[H],Y)` is spiraling off into prolog never-never land because it's unifying `Z` over and over based on your version of Prolog's append.

Change

```
reverse([H|T], Y) :- append(Z, [H], Y), reverse(T, Z).
```

To

```
reverse([H|T], Y) :- reverse(T, Z), append(Z, [H], Y).
```

So that you unify Z before you pass it to `append`

Comment: something has changed, now it finishs with
ERROR: Out of global stack

Comment: @gunt your original code or my suggested code? Out of global stack means it has reached its stack limit and overflowed. (too many recursive calls)

Comment: Sorry, I retried it with your code, it works now!
Introduced a new problem before ;)
Thank you!